# Set PHP with a custom location of the MySQL socket file - mysql.default_socket vs MYSQL_SOCKET

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running mysql-5.6.23 and php-5.6.7 and httpd-2.4.12 on Linux and am trying to see that the phpinfo() displays the correct custom MySQL socket file location I specified in the main php.ini file:

```
mysql.default_socket = /home/stephane/programs/mysql/install/tmp/mysql.sock
```

But even after a server reboot, the phpinfo() keeps on displaying the stock value:

```
MYSQL_SOCKET    /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Here is how I compiled these softwares.

For PHP:

```
./configure \
  --prefix=/home/stephane/programs/install \
  --with-apxs2=/home/stephane/programs/install/apache/bin/apxs \
  --with-config-file-path=/home/stephane/programs/php-5.6.7 \
  --enable-libgcc \
  --with-mysql=/home/stephane/programs/mysql/install \
  --with-zlib-dir=/usr \
  --with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
  --with-png-dir=/usr \
  --with-gd \
  --enable-gd-native-ttf \
  --with-freetype-dir=/usr \
  --enable-ftp \
  --enable-xml \
  --enable-zip \
  --with-bz2 \
  --enable-wddx \
  --without-pear \
  --enable-mbstring \
  --with-curl
```

For MySQL:

```
cmake \
  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/stephane/programs/mysql/install \
  -DWITH_INNOBASE_STORAGE_ENGINE=1 \
  -DMYSQL_DATADIR=/home/stephane/programs/mysql/install/data

scripts/mysql_install_db \
  --no-defaults \
  --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp \
  --basedir=/home/stephane/programs/mysql/install \
  --datadir=/home/stephane/programs/mysql/install/data \
  --tmpdir=/home/stephane/programs/mysql/install/tmp \
  --lc-messages-dir=/home/stephane/programs/mysql/install/share
```

I'm not going to use a work around, like for example specifying the socket file location in the connection statement.

I'm trying to understand how to properly use the mysql.default_socket directive in the php.ini file.

UPDATE:
Is it that the MYSQL_SOCKET value displayed by the phpinfo() function is taken, not from the php.ini file, but from a compile time option set when compiling MySQL ?

So I tried compiling MySQL with the following option this time:
    -DMYSQL_UNIX_ADDR=/home/stephane/programs/mysql/install/tmp/mysql.sock

as in:
cmake \

```
  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/stephane/programs/mysql/install \
  -DWITH_INNOBASE_STORAGE_ENGINE=1 \
  -DMYSQL_DATADIR=/home/stephane/programs/mysql/install/data \
  -DMYSQL_UNIX_ADDR=/home/stephane/programs/mysql/install/tmp/mysql.sock
```

But after also recompiling PHP and restarting Apache, the MYSQL_SOCKET value is still not the custom location one.

Also, this leaves me with the question as to why having two different ways to express a custom MySQL socket location and what is the MYSQL_SOCKET one being used for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare [mysql.default-socket](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php#ini.mysql.default-socket) in **proper** `php.ini` file. I feel that file you have changed is responsible for console-running php configuration.

Check out top section of `phpinfo()` for where from is loaded php.ini file for web server. Should be in `Loaded Configuration File` row.

**Update:** according to comments, assuming that you have configuration set in right file, you should check if php/webserver has read/write acces to `/home/stephane/programs/mysql/install/tmp/mysql.sock` location. Maybe its the reason your config is overriden with defaults.

Comment: What do you mean in the proper file ? The /home/stephane/programs/php-5.6.7/php.ini file is not the proper one ?

Comment: There is only one php.ini file. It is the proper one. I made sure of this by playing with the timezone directive and seeing its value being reflected in the phpinfo() display.

Comment: The phpinfo() shows the correct /home/stephane/programs/php-5.6.7/php.ini file.

Comment: In fact the mysql.default_socket value is correctly set as can be seen in the displayed output of phpinfo(). But it is the value of MYSQL_SOCKET which is not set and remains the original stock one. What is this MYSQL_SOCKET value ? What difference has it with the mysql.default_socket value ?

Comment: The permission on the socket file is not the issue: ll /home/stephane/programs/mysql/install/tmp/mysql.sock
srwxrwxrwx 1 stephane stephane 0 Apr  6 18:01 /home/stephane/programs/mysql/install/tmp/mysql.sock

Comment: Several years old but... you can find the correct PHP file using the output of `phpinfo()`. It's several lines down from the top. It tells you deterministically which `php.ini` filte is being used by the PHP installation that rendered the `phpinfo()`.